# Is this a new virus or adware/malware signature? How do I resolve this?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, malware, virus

Since the last 12 hours or so, I've been facing a virus that's somewhat peculiar. When I open websites, and click any link on those websites, I get a new pop-up tab that opens a link from ad.adsmatte.com or youradexchange.com or something like that.

Currently there are no extensions in my Safari, or the other browsers, in fact. The only recent download that I've made that might be the cause is a torrent version of the film CitizenFour(which seemed trustable enough) using Transmission however, I stopped the download after a couple minutes so I don't think thats the cause. I have deleted those files using rm -rf and before that, I have not downloaded anything except Adobe Flash Updater in the last 3 days. I am quite sure that there are no local manifestations of the virus on my computer, I have used the dashboard and seen that it's not iframe's that I click that lead to this, so it's really weird for a virus.

After googling around a little bit, I landed on a reddit post in /r/linux which is [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/376rj9/virus_warning_adsmatte_youradexchange/). Here's a screenshot of the pop-up using Safari:

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using a 2012 iMac with OS X 10.10.1. This is the 1st time I've ever seen a virus on my mac, and I'm freaking out really, please help... The bug isn't reproducible on other devices including my iPhone, my friend's Ubuntu, so it's not a bug in the website as the post in /r/linux claims..

Also, the software Adwaremedic (version 2.2.3) doesn't detect ad-ware on my mac.

Comment: Why the *heck* are you still on 10.9.1… you're missing a whole slew of security updates. I could understand not wanting 10.10 for now, but to not even update the intermediate versions is just lax. Check your DNS isn't hijacked, at least - https://forms.fbi.gov/check-to-see-if-your-computer-is-using-rogue-DNS

Comment: @Tetsujin I sincerely apologise, Im on 10.10.1, thats yosemite, right ?

Comment: Yes. Probably eliminates more than half my initial concerns :) I'd still check the DNS thing & also get 10.10.3 - I don't think it will immediately fix everything, but it's best to be up to date, in any major release

Comment: @Tetsujin for the other half, I'm using Google DNS, so I guess that's the most secure it can get...

Comment: DNS Hijack doesn't care who you use as a provider [though your ISP is almost always the best one to use, as it's closer to home]

Comment: Also, people, if you read the post in /r/linux on reddit, the person believes that it is a malware of the website, and not the user, is that true ?

Comment: Just to really put a nail in the DNS coffin, if you open terminal app, list the IP address of two web hosts you are having issues surfing. Also, do the ads appear when using this site? `host apple.stackexchange.com` should get you 104.16.13.13 and 104.16.12.13

Comment: Having now actually read the reddit post & tested a few of the 'suspect' sites… I see nothing out of the ordinary at all, even clicking through on sidebar stuff I'd not normally ever touch. So it's either foil hat, something client-side, or they cleared it server-side. [or... my ISP is already blocking whatever it is, can't discard that as an option]

Comment: @bmike the apple.stackexhange.com is listed correctly, and I also don't see ads here... The 1st website I noticed those ads on was `ideone.com` which is listed as having 195.149.198.213 address acc. my computer. One more thing, I'm unable to type into the FBI form(have a slow net connection), my ip address is 192.168.43.87, can someone get that for me ?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know about those sites, can you try `ideone.com` just click the region right below where it says "New code" and around it...

Comment: I get nothing around 'new code' except the actual new code button… which gives me the expected page - even the [wierd] ads just give me the 'expected' ad if I click-though

Comment: @Tetsujin That's good for you, what can I do now ?

Comment: not sure, tbh, but it eliminates the actual site as being the source… or if it is, my gateway or ISP is giving the potential intruder a hard time.

Comment: You should remove the ISP and/or the site from the list of sources, because I have a friend in the same city with an Airtel connection only, and he doesn't get such stuff[I myself have tested]...

Comment: my gateway is not being hit by anything as i test that site, so it's down to my ISP, or your local machine, imo

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987  Take a look at this support guide.

Comment: I think I got it. It's probably an issue related to Indian routers. See [this](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-AdsMatte-spam-popups-and-ads). It's possible a problem in BSNL(an indian company, my ISP).